# Uri is getting removed when removing https?

Tags: magento-1.8, redirect

If I open the URL www.mypage.de/katalog-bestellen in Chrome then the url is automatically changed to "https://www.mypage.de/katalog-bestellen" and the correct site loads.

But If I open the same URL in Edge, then I get redirected to the startpage at `https://www.mypage.de/`.

The uri `katalog-bestellen` is always cut off!

I figured out that changing `Auto Redirect to Base URL` in `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Options` to `No` works, but my SEO professional co-worker told me that this is not a good idea, since google will think that there are two identical websites (www.mypage.de and https://www.mypage.de) and google would see this as "duplicate content" which is bad.

How else can I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like a potential nginx or apache config issue, which are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache

Comment: Check your .htaccess if ther is any down- or upgrading without appending the params to the url

Answer (score 0):

Open the table :

```
core_config_data
```

Then you need fill correct value for two fields :

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
```

Let me know if you have any quesion !

Comment: They are already entered correctly. Both have value: `https://www.mypage.de/`

Comment: You can try change value of field web/secure/use_in_frontend to 1 then clear and check